# Wrong error message when login even username and password is correct

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication, passwords

Whenever I try to login, the message always says `username or password is invalid` eventhough my username and password is correct.

here's my login php code. Also, i used password_hash on my registration.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbcontroller.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        echo "<script>alert('Please input your username and password'); window.location='index.php';</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            // Define $username and $password
            $username=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
            $password=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));

            $query = $conn->query("select * from users where username='$username'");
            $row = $query->fetch_array();
            if (password_verify($password, $row['password']))
            {
                $_SESSION['login_user']=$row['username'];
                header("location: user/home.php?username=$user_check&request=login&status=success"); // Redirecting To Other Page
            }   
            else{
                echo "<script>alert('The username or password you entered is invalid.'); window.location='index.php';</script>";;
            }
            $conn->close(); // Closing Connection

        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: nothing obvious, echo out all variables and queries

Comment: I assume you're doing something wrong with your password hashing

Comment: "select * from users where username='$username'" Here the $username is not taken as a variable. User "select * from users where username='{$username}' "

Comment: I think so too, i've never used password hash before, but in my registration i only did `$new_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` @RobbieAverill

Comment: "*even though my username and password is correct*" Heard *that* one before ;) In the `users` table, per the user in question, does the password value look all *jumbled* up like it's been hashed?

Comment: did that but still the same @ImeshaSudasingha

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha that's just wrong, its enclosed in double quotes

Comment: yes it is. sample pw is like this `$2y$10$vos0HlsPkGXDy` @Marcus

Comment: K good, just checking.

Comment: What is the database column size for the passwords? It needs to be a VARCHAR 255 or larger to account for any changes in the algorithm PHP is likely to change. The length of the hash as it stands should be 60 characters, so your hash is not long enough if that is all you got back.

Comment: You should never use real_escape_string on the password before hashing or while verifying. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79668/login-with-password-hash

Comment: i only have `30` on my database, i'll change that and maybe it'll work. @JayBlanchard

Comment: @eric paste your code of password_verify function

Comment: Geez.. I was about to say both those exact things^^ A. Check the column size, and B. never escape password values (unless you're somehow accommodating it both-ways). Good stuff.

Comment: @sismaster http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: my `password_verify` is already posted above @sismaster

Comment: @eric - FYI, I just hashed a value using `password_hash()` and it came to: **$2y$10$YyeuulAauFz2pWu5/IU.zux8v5pkaRTqhQx.KKv7b9/bAoUGkiz/i** so you need to make sure your `password` column can hold that number of characters.

Comment: okay, i will do that and get back after @Marcus

Comment: i didn't use `escape` on my password during sign up and i changed the value of my password to  `255` and now i have this `$2y$10$eGNnkOlL4ko6G6l.P1VQZuq6LnIxXveEIbIEn/mWMZ5Lk1rAMwGAm` i also tried logging in with my code above and now it's working!!!! thank you SO MUCH guys!!! @Marcus

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha You don't need `{}` around simple variables when interpolating into a string, only complex expressions.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ah, so that's what that link was for ;-) I learned something from that a week or so ago.

Answer (score 1):

*Foreword:* I am not posting this answer for the rep points, so please don't make any assumptions.

The OP can use his own judgement if he wants to mark it as solved, since the question has not been deleted, and no one else posted an answer for it.

> *"i only have 30 on my database, i'll change that and maybe it'll work. @JayBlanchard – eric"*

That's because the column's length is only 50% of what it should be; 60 minimum and ***MySQL has failed you silently***.

As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> *"Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice)."*

---

**What needs to be done.**

You will need to delete the old passwords/hashes, ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash.

Now, as per the link that Jay included in comments:

- [Login with password_hash()](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79668/login-with-password-hash)

...being a link that I found last week (and sent it to him) in regards to a question I asked myself:
*"Should I be escaping a password input?"*.

Well, that link I found after searching on the web, answered my question and he mentions a few other things for it.